# How to Add custom price on single product without affecting to related product?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have code to changes the custom message on all product with 2 different messages. Please take a look.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'show_alert_info_if_no_price');
function show_alert_info_if_no_price ($product){
   if (is_product()) {

        global $product;
        $price = $product->get_price();
        if ($price == '') {
        ob_start();
        // return for the product page
        return '<div class="alert-info">Produk ini hanya dapat diproses melakukan pemesanan pembelian (PO). Segera hubungi tim kami. <a href="contactus.php">Kontak kami</a></div>';
    } else {
        // otherwise return short text as kontak kami 
        return 'Contact us';
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem on related product. I need the related product price will appear like :

> //short text as kontak kami

Now I am stuck how to add another code when using hooked.

```
$woocommerce_loop['name'] != 'related').
```

any help will appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is an mistake in your code, because **this hook is only executed for empty prices**. So going to check in the hook again for an empty price and if it isn't, running an else condition is useless.

To display a different text on the single product page for related products you can use `global $woocommerce_loop`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html( $html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    
    // True on a single product page
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $html = '<div class="alert-info">Produk ini hanya dapat diproses melakukan pemesanan pembelian (PO). Segera hubungi tim kami. <a href="contactus.php">Kontak kami</a></div>';
        
        // Related
        if ( $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) {
            $html = __( 'Some other text', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html', 10, 2 );
```